# PHP - referencing an XML attribute using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Using the simplexml_load_file method, I am trying to retrieve and display the text of all name elements (from an XML file below) that have an attribute named "type' with the value of 'tablet.' This foreach loop is only displaying the value of the first element. Any advice? Thanks!

```
$XMLproducts = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
foreach($XMLproducts->product->attributes() as $a => $b) {
  $i = 0;
  if ($b == "Tablet") {
    echo $XMLproducts->product[$i]->name;
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<products>

  <product type="Desktop">
   <name>Desktop 1</name>
  </product>

  <product type="Tablet">
    <name>Ipad 1</name>
  </product>

  <product type="Desktop">
    <name>Desktop 2</name>
  </product>

  <product type="Tablet">
    <name>Ipad 2</name>
  </product>

</products>
```

Comment: You'll need to do 2 loops: `foreach($XMLproducts->product as $product){ foreach($product->attributes() as $a => $b){ if($b=='Tablet') echo $product->name;}}.` (or use 1 Xpath: `/product[@type="Tablet"]/name`).

Comment: Look at using http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php, it is a godsend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scuzzy mentioned in the comments, using [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) simplifies the solution:

```
foreach ($XMLproducts->xpath('/products/product[@type="Tablet"]/name') as $name) {
    echo $name , "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $XMLproducts = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
 foreach($XMLproducts->products->product as $product) {
   foreach ($product->attributes() as $a => $b) {
      $i = 0;
      if ($b == "Tablet") {
         echo $XMLproducts->product[$i]->name;
         echo "<br>";
      }
   }
 }
```